# problem while POSTing to the server in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm learning Express and I face an issue which I can't understand.
When I route to `/addPerson` I expect to log the `name: 'Mike', age: 30` to the console. Instead I got nothing logged to the console. What's wrong in my code?

here's the `server.js` code

```
const Express = require('express'),
      app     = Express(),
      PORT    = process.env.PORT || 5000,
      parser  = require('body-parser'),
      data    = []

// initialize the main project folder
app.use(Express.static('public'))

// running the server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at port ${PORT}`);
})

// include body parser to handle POST requests
app.use(parser.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(parser.json())

// setup CORS
const cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())

// GET request
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Home Page</h1>')
})
app.get('/addPerson', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hello Hany</h1>')
})

// POST request
app.post('/addPerson', (req, res) => {
    data.push(req.body)
    console.log(data);
})
```

and here is the client side `app.js` code

```
const postData = async ( url = '', data = {})=>{
    console.log(data);
      const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST', 
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
     // Body data type must match "Content-Type" header        
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });

      try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        console.log(newData);
        return newData;
      }catch(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
      }
  }

postData('/addPerson', {name: 'Mike', age: 30});
```

this the files structure

[image]

Comment: Just to double check, you're running both the server and app on the same port right? If you are try setting your url as `http://localhost:5000/addPerson` and see if that works.

Comment: yes, I'm running both on the same port 5000. And it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I've taken a look at your code and this is what I've noticed. Within your `server.js` file you have this code block:

```
app.get('/addPerson', (req, res) => {
    res.send('<h1>Hello Hany</h1>')
})
```

That is sending back a static H1 tag when the user creates a get request to `localhost:5000/addPerson`. Then, directly below that you have your post route but you're never fully accessing that from anywhere (I looked through all your `app.js` code to double check).

Instead, I have changed your code to return a static html file with a button that allows you to call this function (just as an example so you can see that your routes do in fact work). This isn't the cleanest solution to your problem but I just wanted to make sure you see where the problem lies as I've been in your shoes before when I first started working with express. You can take a look at the CodeSandbox I setup below to replicate your issue and take a look through all the code to get an understanding.

[image: Edit sweet-goldberg-1iecz]

To properly solve your issue using the `app.js` file you would have to serve the javscript file as your "frontend". Personally I'm a big fan of [React](https://reactjs.org/) so I usually serve my frontend with React, while my backend is express. You can also very easily serve this file using NodeJS in a similar fashion that you are with your "backend". If you were to take the React approach you would be able to modify this code:

```js
app.get("/addPerson", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "public", "index.html"));
});
```

To find the frontend section you desire using React (I can recommend react-router if you require multiple routes but I don't want to overwhelm you with too much information yet) and complete the same function. If you have any questions feel free to reach out and let me know! Hopefully this helps!